# Do I need a specific package for "\N"

Tags: packages

The wikepedia page [Folge](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folge_%28Mathematik%29) has this formula (under *Formale Definition*)

```
\begin{matrix} a:&\N &\to &X\\ & i &\mapsto &a_i, \end{matrix}
```

where `\N` is  used for the set of natural numbers. I am able to create its symbol with a `\mathbb{N}`. But when I use `\N`, I get the error `! Undefined control sequence.`.

I assume I need to use a specific package in order to have `\N` defined. Is this so and if so, which one is it?

Comment: no just define `\N` yourself: `\usepackage{amsfonts}  \newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}`

Comment: I see. Does wikipedia do this definition "behind the scenes"?

Comment: Instead of that font I use `dsfonts` package, which defines `\mathds{}` instead of `\mathbb{}` and gives you better output (in my opinion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also define that yourself:

```
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
```

I am not aware of any package that will define `\N` for you, but if it does, it will probably look like the definition I gave.

Comment: Isn't necessary to load `amsfonts` first, like in David Carlisle's comment to the question?

Comment: @mbork Yes and no. Any package that defines `\mathbb` will do: `amsfonts`, `mbboard`, `mathbbol`, `bbold` ... Chose what you like more.

Comment: ah well you need to load _some package_ to define `\mathbb` (nut same is true of `matrix`) . It is the amsfonts package (if you want the ams version of mathbb) that actually defines `\mathbb` although some of the other ams packages load this automatically of course/